# Как проследить по каким URL'ам ходит Android приложение?

Tags: android

День добрый, возник вопрос, как проследить куда обращается приложение на Андроиде? Если есть возможность, то ещё было бы интересно посмотреть какой ответ от сервера получает

Comment: установите на декстоп любой прокси сервер и в настройках андроида укажите эту прокси.

Comment: Вроде в CAT логаг видно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запускай на эмуляторе и смотри через [WireShark](www.wireshark.org)

Answer (score 2):

Отладочный прокси-сервер Fiddler является отличным инструментом для захвата и отладки http трафика.

Fiddler поддерживает расширение своих возможностей путём написания скриптов на JScript.

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler